# custom class inheriting from UIButton not detected in isKindOfClass:

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I've created a custom button class with some extra properties that inherits from UIButton. It is added in a view like following with a normal button:

```
EFButton *btn = [EFButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];    
btn.frame = CGRectMake(500, 100, 100, 44);
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
btn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[self.view addSubview:btn];

UIButton *nBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];    
nBtn.frame = CGRectMake(500, 100, 100, 44);
nBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
nBtn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[self.view addSubview:nBtn];
```

Looping through the objects in view like:

```
  for (id view in self.view.subviews) 
{

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[EFButton class]]) 
    {
        //** dsnt come here **
        NSLog(@"EFButton Class");
        EFButton *btn = view;
    }
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
    {
        //** come here **
        NSLog(@"UIButton Class");
        UIButton *btn = view;
    }
}
```

UIButton is works but it does not come in the condition of isKindOfClass:[EFButton class]. Please help me with what i'm doing wrong or how it needs to be done.

Answer (score 5):

It is because `buttonWithType` is a class method of `UIButton` , it returns `UIButton` type , although your `EFButton` inherits `UIButton` , it can't return  `EFButton`  type

Quote the developer [documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

```
If you subclass UIButton, this method does not return an instance of your subclass
```

PS: I do not think inheriting `UIButton` is a good way.

Comment: Yes, if you didn't write an implementation of `buttonWithType:` in `EFButton` this is what's happening. Also, `UIButtonTypeCustom` is there for you to avoid subclassing...

Comment: What can be done in order to add some extra properties in the UIButton Class.

Comment: @HassanWaheed you can add a Category for the UIButton , to add extra "properties".faking instance variables for UIButton.(how to do you can look at this : http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/)

Comment: you can use alloc and init to create a button.althout it looks strange. but it is from the developer documents.I tried the init method,it work.so you need not to add a category.just subclass is ok.