# UIButton subclass: does buttonWithType: return UIButton or subclass instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

If I subclass `UIButton` and use its `buttonWithType:` method to create a `button`, does it return me a `UIButton` or subclass instance?

For example:

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton
@end

MyButton *button = [MyButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Or I have to use `alloc` and `initWithFrame` instead?

Thanks

Comment: It should be normal initialization as you do for UIButton, you just subclassing the UIButton class, this means your class implements all the behavior of the parent class, and you can add extra functionalities too, and can be used like the way you do for simple UIButton, but you have to define the class for your button instead of UIButton *myButton; you have to write MyButton *myButton; thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buttonWithType` is a `class method` of `UIButton` , it return `UIButton` type , although your `MyButton` inherits `UIButton` , it also can not return `MyButton` type

more info you can see my answer before : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555717/custom-class-inheriting-from-uibutton-not-detected-in-iskindofclass/14555793#14555793)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I just found this from Apple's doc:

> This method is a convenience constructor for creating button objects with specific configurations. It you subclass UIButton, this method does not return an instance of your subclass. If you want to create an instance of a specific subclass, you must alloc/init the button directly.

Comment: You can also just NSLog the returned object. The default description string prints the object class name (actual class). Helpful for a quick answer to "what type of thing is this?" in debug/test mode.